# Elaborar múltiples tablas de frecuencias en R usando for loops

Tags: r

Tengo un data frame `web_main` con 18 variables, a las cuales tengo que sacar tablas de frecuencia. Los hago de esta forma usando el paquete dplyr

```
boletin <- web_main %>%
  group_by(`¿Deseas que te incluyamos en nuestro Boletín Informativo?`) %>%
  count() %>%
  mutate(prop = n / 523)
```

Quisiera crear un for loop o por algún otro medio poder reciclar este código para crear las tablas que necesito y no estar copiando y pegando 18 veces el mismo código

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Voy a crear un ejemplo reproducible con algo q se pueda asimilar a tus datos:

```r
library(tidyverse)

web_main <- data.frame(a=sample(1:2,size = 100, replace = T))

boletin <- web_main %>% group_by(a) %>% count() %>% mutate(prop =n/dim(web_main)[1])

boletin
## # A tibble: 2 × 3
##       a     n  prop
##   <int> <int> <dbl>
## 1     1    45  0.45
## 2     2    55  0.55
```

Para poder iterar por columnas y crear tablas de frecuencia, usa la función `map` del paquete `purrr` (misma sintaxis que `dplyr`, ya que también es una paquete de Hadley Wickhman):

```r
library(purrr)

web_main <- data.frame(a=sample(1:2,size = 100, replace = T),
                       b=sample(1:100,size = 100, replace = T),
                       c=sample(1:50,size = 100, replace = T),
                       d=sample(1:25,size = 100, replace = T),
                       e=sample(1:10,size = 100, replace = T),
                       f=sample(1:100,size = 100, replace = T),
                       g=sample(1:50,size = 100, replace = T),
                       h=sample(1:25,size = 100, replace = T),
                       i=sample(1:10,size = 100, replace = T),
                       j=sample(1:2,size = 100, replace = T),
                       k=sample(1:2,size = 100, replace = T),
                       l=sample(1:5,size = 100, replace = T),
                       m=sample(1:5,size = 100, replace = T),
                       n=sample(1:2,size = 100, replace = T),
                       o=sample(1:2,size = 100, replace = T),
                       p=sample(1:25,size = 100, replace = T),
                       q=sample(1:50,size = 100, replace = T),
                       r=sample(1:5,size = 100, replace = T))

boletines <- web_main %>% map(`[`) %>% map(function(.x){
  as_data_frame(.x) %>%
    arrange(.x) %>%
    group_by(value) %>%
    count() %>%
    mutate(prop = n/sum(n))})
```

La función `map` itera por elementos, al usar `map(`[`)` (con las tildes inversas que no logran aparecer) selecciono cada columna. Luego, con otro `map` convierto cada iteración a `data.frame`, ordeno los elementos (gusto personal) y realizo el mismo proceso que propusiste, todo dentro de una única función. El resultado es una lista con las tablas de frecuencia. He aquí la primera y la última:

```r
boletines[[1]]
## # A tibble: 2 × 3
##   value     n  prop
##   <int> <int> <dbl>
## 1     1    56  0.56
## 2     2    44  0.44

boletines[[18]]
## # A tibble: 5 × 3
##   value     n  prop
##   <int> <int> <dbl>
## 1     1    19  0.19
## 2     2    16  0.16
## 3     3    20  0.20
## 4     4    21  0.21
## 5     5    24  0.24
```